# Easiest way to get delta between two DataFrames

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks, delta

I am working within Microsoft Azure Databricks with two Dataframes.

I have already a Dataframe which contains my "Masterdata". I am receiving daily also a full data package with "all" records. But those within this Dataframe there can be changes within records and records could be also deleted and added.

What is the best and maybe easiest way to get this delta or changset of data between two Dataframes?

**UPDATE**
DataFrame 1 -> which i am getting every day

```
customer  score
MERCEDES  1.1
CHRYSLER  3.0
```

DataFrame 2 -> my master

```
customer score
BMW       1.1
MERCEDES  1.3
```

So what do i need to get:

```
customer score
BMW       1.1    -> cause was deleted in receiving data
MERCEDES  1.3    -> cause was value changed
CHRYSLER  3.0    -> cause was added new
```

Comment: have you tried the merge function?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i dont want to merge both dataframes instead i want to compare and extract the differences.

Comment: Okay, see if you can put together some sample dataframes to reflect the type of data you are getting. it will give us an idea what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the merge function. See if it works for you.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['MERCEDES','CHRYSLER'], 'score':[1.1, 3.0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['BMW','MERCEDES'], 'score':[1.1, 1.3]})

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['customer'], how='outer',indicator=True)
df
```

see the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to append a received date column '`RDate`' to each of the dataframe. Then concatenate the two dataframes. using `sort by` you then pick the latest value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['MERCEDES','CHRYSLER'], 'score':[1.1, 3.0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'customer':['BMW','MERCEDES'], 'score':[1.1, 1.3]})
df2['RDate']='2018-11-01'
df1['RDate']='2018-11-07'

mdf = pd.concat([df1, df2])
mdfs =mdf.sort_values(by='RDate')
mdfs.drop_duplicates('customer', keep='last')
```

original concatenated dataframes:

[image]

final (duplicates dropped):

[image]

Comment: MEdwin thanks for the work! But this is the final result of the data. What i need is to really get the changes, added and deleted as separeted Dataframes so that i can work with it. Is this also possible?

Comment: okay, I think what you need is just the merge function. It will let you know if the score is contained in both the new and old dataframe, and right_only means it is a new entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try like:

```
>>> df1
   customer score
0  MERCEDES   1.1
1  CHRYSLER   3.0

>>> df2
   customer score
0       BMW   1.1
1  MERCEDES   1.3
```

Concatenate the df1 & df2 on the columns..

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
```

Now you can use `groupby` with customer as that's the Key for update with `last(offset)` method  which is Convenient for for subsetting final periods of time series data

```
>>> df.groupby(['customer'], as_index=False).last()
   customer score
0       BMW   1.1
1  CHRYSLER   3.0
2  MERCEDES   1.3
```

`as_index=False` is effectively "SQL-style" grouped output while using with `groupby`